# Make a rollable item menu list using Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I would insert a rollable menu list in my ViewController, as in the follow app:

[image]

How can I make it using Xcode?
how is called this type of menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIPickerView` is what you want to display it.
Check documentation on this with more info https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/

To be able to use an image and text inside `UIPickerView`'s row, you should override next function from `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol and provide your implementation of it:

```
func viewForRow(_ row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> UIView?
```

Comment: Perfect!! I follow your suggestion and I found the PickerView

UIPickerView:
Provides a potentially multidimensional user-interface element consisting of rows and components. A component is a wheel, which has a series of items (rows) at indexed locations on the wheel. Each row on a component has content, which is either a string or a view object such as a label or an image.